# Simple example of RoudnRobinGroup in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I couldn't find worked example of RoundRobingGroup in Akka (examples in documentation couldn't help me). I want to tie two actors in one RoundRobinGroup and just send simple message with Akka (via router variable), but i always receive the deadletter in logs.

```
 object Main extends App { 
      val system = ActorSystem()

      val paths = List("w1", "w2")
      val w1 = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "w1")
      val w2 = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "w2")
      val router = system.actorOf(new RoundRobinGroup(paths).props(), "shard")

      router ! "hello"
}
```

I would like to know where is my mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It resolved my problem

```
   class Master extends Actor {    
          var router = {
            val routees = Vector.fill(2) {
              val mappings = context.actorOf(Props[HelloActor])
              context watch mappings
              ActorRefRoutee(mappings)
            }
            Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
          }

          def receive = {
            case message: String =>
              router.route(message, sender())
            case Terminated(a) =>
              router = router.removeRoutee(a)
              val r = context.actorOf(Props[HelloActor])
              context watch r
              router = router.addRoutee(r)
          }
        }

        class HelloActor extends Actor {
          override def receive: Receive = {
            case "hello" => println("Another actor said hello")
            case _ => println("Unrecognized message")
          }
        }

        object Main extends App {
          val system = ActorSystem()
          val master = system.actorOf(Props[Master], name = "parent")
          master ! "hello"
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the error , as we do not have all day to look the error in the code ! Please understand

Comment: I resolved my problem. Can you check this code on "bad places" (i edited post above), please.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a Router with two instances of HelloActor and Routers
and use the RoundRobinRoutingLogic as the routing Logic. 
You can get a detailed info here : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html

Hope I solved your problem !

Comment: Thank you, but in what place i should append `RounRobinRoutingLogic` to my "hello world" app (maybe it's stupid question, but documentation consists of not completed and scattered example)?

Comment: See this example they have defined it http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#A_Simple_Router 

Make the router and use the RounRobinRoutingLogic along with it. You can also define it in the configuration. 
If it helped you please upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: I made as you told me, can you help me to find the mistake (in post below)?